# WSO2 Micro Integrator - DBReport Mediator Return Generated Keys

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

By using DBReport mediator I executed insert function to my database table. After successful insert operation is it possible to return the auto incremented key value of the record?

Comment: Have the same question. Is there an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps to return the auto incremented key by using `DBLookup`:

1. Query string:

   ```
   insert into Students(Name) values(?); 
   select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as ID
   ```
2. Check "Results Enabled"
3. Add new Result: `(PropertyName: NewID, Column Id: ID)`

I tried the same approach with `DBReport`, but it didn't work.